# Detect whether a Linux execution host is cloud based or not

Tags: linux, cloud, dmidecode

Presently I'm checking by running dmidecode -s bios-version and grepping against major cloud vendors. Ex:
`# From an amazon ec2 VM
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
4.2.amazon`

Is there a generic and more reliable approach for finding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism by which cloud vendors inject identification into running virtual machines.  If your goal is to detect whether or not your are running in a virtual environment you could use the [virt-what](https://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) command, but there is no good way to differentiate one cloud vendor from another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code using which you can detect the popular bare metal vendors like AWS, Azure, Google Cloud and Oracle.
This will return None if it cannot detect cloud.
https://github.com/nithinj/cloud_what

Answer (score 0):

Even as non-root
`lsmod` on azure shows lots of hyperv/hv_ references, I'm assuming aws will show something that can be interpreted as kvm or xen

(posting as an answer because I don't have enough rep)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/440943)